# Use Htmx to update Bokeh plot in a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, bokeh, htmx

I have a Flask app that displays a Bokeh plot using [Htmx](https://htmx.org). The plot uses x and y values from the form inputs. Each time the form is submitted, the entire Bokeh plot is redrawn which creates a new plot figure. I would prefer to only update the Bokeh plot with the new x and y values instead of creating a new plot figure. Bokeh has a [ColumnDataSource](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#providing-data-as-a-columndatasource) which appears to provide a method to update the data instead of creating an entirely new plot figure. So my question is, how do I use this `ColumnDataSource` with Htmx to update the plot's data?

[image: flask bokeh plot]

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/plot', methods=['POST'])
def plot():
    # Get the form inputs
    xdata = request.form['xdata']
    ydata = request.form['ydata']

    # Convert form input to a list of floats representing x and y values
    x = list(map(float, xdata.split(', ')))
    y = list(map(float, ydata.split(', ')))

    # Create a Bokeh plot using the x and y values
    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
    p.circle(x, y, size=12, line_color='navy', fill_color='orange')

    # Get HTML components to embed in a web page
    script, div = components(p)

    return render_template('plot.html', script=script, div=div)
```

The HTML templates are shown below.

```html
<!-- templates/index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.2.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Home Page</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body { background-color: lightgray; }
        input { max-width: 200px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col">
                <h1 class="mt-3">Submit data</h1>

                <p>Input the x and y data points using comma separated values.</p>

                <form hx-post="/plot" hx-target="#graph" hx-trigger="load, submit">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="xdata" class="form-label">X data</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="xdata" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="ydata" class="form-label">Y data</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ydata" value="6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 3.2, 4">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <h1 class="mt-3">Plot data</h1>

                <p>Below is a line plot using the X and Y data points.</p>

                <div id="graph"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1" integrity="sha384-tvG/2mnCFmGQzYC1Oh3qxQ7CkQ9kMzYjWZSNtrRZygHPDDqottzEJsqS4oUVodhW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- templates/plot.html -->

{{ script | safe }}
{{ div | safe }}
```

Comment: I don't know anything at all about HTMX but if it necessitates hitting an endpoint then there is probably a tension with your stated goal. Absent a running Bokeh server, the CDS would have to be updated *from JavaScript* so you would need a mechanism that resulted in running a snippet of JS code to update the CDS as a result of hitting that endpoint.

Comment: Htmx gives you access to AJAX, WebSockets, and server sent events directly in HTML. I think Bokeh has a Javascript implementation so maybe using the Javascript version would be a better approach.

Comment: Yes there is a BokehJS library that does most of the actual work, but as a user-facing tool it is somewhat less developed than the Python side of things. You can find some documentation for it here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html and for any bundling or package questions I would highly recommend submitting a [GitHub Disucussion](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/discussions) in order to reach the maintainers with the most expertise.